# RSpec Matchers for function arguments

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm new to writing custom matchers, and most of the examples cover a very minimal set up. What's the proper way to write a matcher that extends a function from a module that has an argument. Do I need to give the actual block the function argument `input`? Thanks.

```
# My Example:
RSpec::Matchers.define :total do |expected|
  match do |input, actual|
    actual.extend(Statistics).sample(input) == expected
  end
end

# Before:
describe Statistics do
  it 'should not be empty' do
    expect(Statistics.sample(input)).not_to be_empty
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it depends on what you want to test. If you merely want to test that the module includes a method, maybe something like this:

```
module Statistics
  def sample
  end
end

class Test
end

RSpec::Matchers.define :extend_with do |method_name|
  match do |klass|
    klass.extend(Statistics).respond_to?(method_name)
  end
end

describe Statistics do
  subject { Test.new }
  it { should extend_with(:sample) }
end
```

If you want to test the value returned, you can add that as an argument, or chain the matcher:

```
module Statistics
 def sample(input)
    41 + input
  end
end

class Test
end

RSpec::Matchers.define :extend_with do |method_name, input|
  match do |klass|
    @klass = klass
    @klass.extend(Statistics).respond_to?(method_name)
  end
  chain :returning_value do |value|
    @klass.extend(Statistics).__send__(method_name, input) == value
  end
end

describe Statistics do
  subject { Test.new }
  it { should extend_with(:sample) }
  it { should extend_with(:sample, 2).returning_value(43) }
end
```

The matcher DSL is quite flexible. You don't have to be hung up on naming your arguments 'actual' and 'expected' like in the [docs](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/2-14/docs/custom-matchers) -- write the specs so they tell the story of your code.

Comment: Excellent answer. For this spec, I just want to be able to call my method sample with input. So, instead of respond_to? I would call sample(input). input represent a string that gets converted to an array. So I would like to be able to call it like this: ```expect('10,20,30').to sum_up_to(60.0)``` Also, me module is just class methods.